# Motivating Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intuition, zariski-topology

I always find it difficult to motivate Zariski topology on $\text{Spec}(k[X_1,...,X_n])$, both the underlying set and the topology. As far as I understand, Zariski topology isn't really that essential for proving many classical theorems like Bezout's (for example Fischer doesn't mention Zariski topology once in his *Plane Algebraic Curves*); applications of Zariski topology where it does play an essential role are probably too advanced for me (although counterexamples are much appreciated).

Then I wonder if I can at least motivate Zariski topology intrinsically. I can somehow agree with the naturalness of Zariski topology on $k^n$: points should be closed and polynomials should be continuous; this is a bit like weak topology in functional analysis. But why do we want to consider prime ideals, i.e., to put points and irreducible varieties on the same footing? A usual answer is that preimage of maximal ideal is in general not maximal, but it *is* maximal in the case of finitely generated $k$-algebras, which seems good enough (and why is it so important to take preimage?). Also, why should we think of the zero ideal as the "generic point"? For me it's hard to relate that to those classical generic point arguments.

But now I think I finally found a way to motivate Zariski topology. Please help me check if the math is correct.

1. Let $K\supseteq k$ be a larger algrabraically closed field of infinite transcendence degree, e.g., if $k=Q^{\text{alg}}$ then we may take $K=\mathbb{C}$. For each $a=(a_1,...,a_n)\in K^n$, define $\pi(a)=\{f\in k[X_1,...,X_n]: f(a)=0\}$. This is a prime ideal.
2. We claim that $\pi:K^n\rightarrow\text{Spec}(k[X_1,...,X_n])$ is surjective. For any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, the image of $X_1,...,X_n$ in $k[X_1,...,X_n]/\mathfrak{p}$ is a tuple that satisfies exactly those polynomials in $\mathfrak{p}$. The algebraic closure of $k[X_1,...,X_n]/\mathfrak{p}$ has transcendence degree at most $n$ over $k$, and hence embeds into $K$.
3. We claim that with both $K^n$ and $\text{Spec}(k[X_1,...,X_n])$ endowed with Zariski topology, $\pi$ is a closed map, hence a quotient map. If $f(a)=0$ then $\pi(a)\ni f$; conversely if $\mathfrak{p}\ni f$, choose any $a$ that maps to $\mathfrak{p}$, and we must have $f(a)=0$. This shows the image of a basic closed set in $K^n$ is a basic closed set in $\text{Spec}(k[X_1,...,X_n])$; the general case is similar.

So the Zariski topology on $\text{Spec}(k[X_1,...,X_n])$ is just the quotient of the (in my opinion) more intuitive topology on $K^n$. As for generic point, if $\pi(a)=\mathfrak{p}$ then the tuple $a$ satisfies those polynomials in $\mathfrak{p}$ and nothing else, as with "most" $K$-points on the variety determined by $\mathfrak{p}$; in particular $\pi(a)=(0)$ iff $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ are algebraically independent. This makes more sense to me than "$(0)$ is a point that lies everywhere". As for the reason of going to a larger field $K$: truly generic point doesn't exist if we only look at $k$. All algebraically closed fields (of a fixed characteristic) are more or less the same, so the structure of varieties don't really change when we move to a larger field.

Is this a useful way to picture Zariski topology? Perhaps it's too early for me, but is this related to the the [functor of points](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functorial+geometry)?

Comment: This business with the algebraically closed field of infinite transcendence degree reminds me of Weil's foundations - this was the attempt at algebraic geometry right before Grothendieck's perspective took over and it was famously somewhat awful to understand, so I'm glad at least someone finds it slightly useful. In general I would not say this is a good motivation for most people - really, we know from the nullstellensatz that if we care about subvarieties we care about prime ideals, so what if we just made those our space? It turns out to go pretty well :)

Comment: @KReiser Sure Nullstellensatz gives a correspondence, but irreducible varieties are subsets of the affine space; why add those subsets as points into the affine space to get a new space? I never understand the "geometry" here, it looks like pure black magic - until now

Comment: Are you familiar with the struggles of the Italian school of the 19th/20th century around the "generic point"? It turns out that if you literally add the generic point to your space, things work out. You don't have to always think of the new points if you don't want to - visualizing everything the way you were doing before for fields is perfectly fine, but the fact that those points exist lets you keep track and deal with a lot more even just in the case of varieties over fields.

Comment: @xXF If you are working with varieties over an algebraically closed field, there is in some sense no point: an algebraic variety (say, affine or quasi-projective) is uniquely defined by its closed points. But the $\text{Spec}$ point of view allows you to work with non-algebraically closed fields, where some prime ideals don't correspond to any subsets in the naive sense, and non-reduced schemes, for example, letting you make sense of the difference between the zeroes of $x$ and zeroes of $x^2$.

Comment: @KReiser So I was right that $\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Spec}$ should be thought of as a generic point on $V(\mathfrak{p})$? Truly generic point can be found only in $K$, but if all we need is "sufficiently generic point (away from finitely many prescribed subvarieties)" then $k$ is enough, I guess that's why the spec approach works out? I was really just wanting to understand why $(0)$ deserves the name "generic point".

Comment: @SergeyGuminov I think I actually don't need $k$ to be algebraically closed; prime ideal can still be understood as "points in extension".

Comment: Yes, you should think of $\mathfrak{p}$ as the generic point of $V(\mathfrak{p})$. In fact, by the usual modern definition of a generic point, it **is** the generic point.